# How do I migrate from the Taxonomy Access Control module to the Group module?

Tags: migrations, taxonomy-terms

We have a Drupal 6 site, and we are making use of the [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module for access control. We evaluated the migration steps, and even if that module could be ported to Drupal 8, we could use a different approach.

We are evaluating the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module as an alternative to content access control, but there are no automatic path to migrate from. What would the preferred migration path be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation: go for such replacement. In doing so, you could use the approach detailed in [How to bulk assign content to a group](https://www.drupal.org/node/2712619). This community documentation page explains how you can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module together with the [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to bulk-assigning existing content to groups.

Here is the Rules Component included in that page (in Rules export format):

```
{ "rules_assign_a_node_to_a_group" : {
    "LABEL" : "Assign a node to a group",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ACCESS_EXPOSED" : "1",
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "node" : { "label" : "Node", "type" : "node" },
      "group" : { "label" : "Group", "type" : "group" }
    },
    "ACTION SET" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:group" ], "value" : [ "group" ] } } ]
  }
}
```

Refer to the community page mentioned above for more details.

PS: the above rule assumes your migration target is D7 (there is no stable Rules release for D8 yet ...). But by using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module you're in very good shape also to later on upgrade to D8 also, since this module supports both releases.